# jQuery JSON inside an ajax call

Tags: jquery, json

In my application I have a login using ajax that returns a JSON result.

If it's a success then it will return as:

`{"authenticated":true,"redirect":"/posts/new"}`

If it's a fail then:

`{"authenticated":false,"error":"Username or password is incorrect"}`

What I want to do is inside my ajax Success callback is check what authentication is and if it's true then do one thing and if it's false then do another:

```
success: function (responseHtml)
{
    if(SUCCESS IS TRUE)
    {
          window.location.href('REDIRECT');
    }
    else
    {        
          alert('ERROR MESSAGE');
    }

    console.log(responseHtml);
}
```

Can anyone help me? I have had a look at the getJSON stuff but not sure how to use it here. Thanks

UPDATE: full code

```
$('form').live('submit', function (event) {

            var form = $(this);

            event.preventDefault();

            var data = form.serialize();

            $('<div id="loading">Loading...</div>').appendTo('#li-submit').hide();

            $('#loading').fadeIn();

            $.ajax({
                type: form.attr('method'),
                url: form.attr('action'),
                data: data,
                success: function (response)
                {
                    $('#loading').fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove(); });

                    if(response.authenticated)
                    {
                         window.location.href('url');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                         alert(response.error);
                    }
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
                {
                    $('#loading').fadeOut(function() { $(this).remove(); });

                    alert('Error!');
                }

            });

        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
success: function(response) {
    if(response.authenticated) {
         window.location.href('url');
    } else {
         alert('error');
    }
}
```

You should make sure that the 'dataType' attribute of your AJAX config object is set to "json" or not set (it will default to auto-detect).

Comment: in this case change `success: function (responseHtml)` to `success: function (response)`

Comment: Oh good point. I had renamed it because "responseHtml" would not have been HTML, but JSON. I shall update, thank you.

Comment: yep responseHtml does not make sense

Comment: The data type is POST as the form is posting to the server. See OP for full ajax code

Comment: No, "type" is POST. "dataType" is "json". "dataType" refers to the type of the AJAX response, not the request.

Answer (score 0):

```
// if response is already json as you said 
success: function (response) {
    if(response && response.authenticated) {
      window.location = response.redirect;
    } else {        
      alert('ERROR MESSAGE');
    }

    console.log(response);
}
```